# Wpf divided textbox in several section and Navigate between different parts

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, textbox, keyboard

I'm developer wpf project and use mvvm design pattern.
I want one of a textbox to divided in several section in wpf and navigate between different parts of them with tab key.
How can I implement it?

Comment: That's called "several text boxes".

Comment: @EdPlunkett yes. For example: Implement license plate with one textbox, But, Each distinct parts

Comment: No. Use one TextBox control for each part. Make each part a separate TextBox control. If there are three parts, use three TextBoxes. One TextBox for each part. I know exactly what you want to do. Don't do that. You can hide the borders to make them LOOK like it's all one TextBox. But use several TextBoxes.

Comment: Use several Textboxs, or you can do that on dirty way with the carret position.